# Downloading jGrasp or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, jgrasp

I've just started a Java Programming module in college, during our tutorials we're using `jGrasp`.

I want to be able to practice at home on my laptop so I've tried downloading `jGrasp` and also Eclipse. I've talked to a friend who said Eclipse would be better to use but I want to use `jGrasp` as I will be doing so all year and for my project.

But I've had some trouble trying to download `jGrasp` and Eclipse. I've googled several so-called "easy ways" to download the programs but when they've been installed I end up deleting them straight away as they never work.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me once and for all, what I need to do EXACTLY, in order to get `jGrasp` or Eclipse installed and ready to go on my laptop.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds to me like you either do not have a JDK or you do not have JAVA_HOME set in your environment.. or both.

Comment: Yes, be more specific as to what problems you are running into. Why are you deleting them straight away? What error are you seeing? Also, I would recommend not using JGrasp. You can easily load projects made in Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.. into JGrasp at school if that is your goal. Eclipse and Netbeans give you much more control of the IDE, including extensions and other useful tools that you will find helpful as you continue to enhance your programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing the same issue I experianced during my first time. You are missing a compiler I think. Install a compiler such as Mingw or Cygwin and select that compiler by opening JGrasp > setting > compiler setting> file. Then select the compiler you just installed and apply it, then click done/ok. Now go to the bin directory of JGrasp and copy the address. Open the environment variable from Path. DO NOT delete it. Just add a semicolon ; with it and after the semicolon paste the bin address. Click done/ok. 
That's it!

Answer (score 0):

To use a java ide, you must download the java development kit(JDK) from oracle.com Its a simple download and install. Now you can code in java.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

To download jGrasp, go to there website, on the left there is a button that says download. If you scroll to the very bottom there are links for download. Make sure you pick the right link for the type of operating system on your laptop.

Eclipse is widely known as one of the best java ide. That being said if you are just learning, jGrasp is a great way to learn the language, it has a great visual debugger and is very simple to use compared to Eclipse. If you are doing complex programs Eclipse can assist you with things like syntax and logical errors. Eclipse has a lot more pretty themes too:)